# How to prevent spam in admin files via form in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, captcha, spam, spam-prevention, email-spam

There are lot of spam files coming on daily basis and showing in admin `(http://domainname.com/admin/content/file)` and also having a pattern with alphanumeric (ie. vhjhgjb123.pdf) as you can see in the attached image. I think these spams are coming via forms.

So for preventing this I have enabled image captcha in all the forms but still these spams are coming regularly. Please help me to figure out this.
[image]

Comment: Which are you core version drupal 7 ?

Comment: yes.. its drupal 7

Comment: I know but i want to know i you have the latest version of core ? 7.5x ?? Higher ??

Comment: Its 7.39 version of drupal.

Comment: you need to update your core version , several security issues are patched into https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.61